# When do Yekkes first don a kittel?

Tags: minhag, clothing, kittel, yekke

I read on Machon Moreshes Ashkenaz's forums [Wedding Minhagim](http://www.kayj.net/en/forum/minhogim/169-wedding-minhogim) that it is the German custom not to wear a kittel or sargenes under the chuppah. I know that it is worn on Rosh Hashannah and Yom Kippur, as well as by the shliach tzibbur on Hoshanna Rabbah; some also wear it at other times, but those three are the only ones specified by MMA, which does not say what the first occasion for wear is. Does anyone know when it is first worn?

Comment: By using "first" you seem to be assuming it is worn altogether. Why do you think so? And I'd think that knowledge would also tell you when it's *first* worn (e.g., if you know it's worn because it's worn on _Yom Kipur_ by married men, then presumably it's first worn at the first _Yom Kipur_ of a man's marriage), no? I feel like this question is missing something, like it leaves out some knowledge that you have that can help get your question answered. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my knowledge - having grown up in the Yekkish Kehilla of Johannesburg and Strasbourg:

Yekkes do not wear a Kittel/Sargenes during their first year of marriage.

Some Yekkes do not wear a Kittel/Sargenes  on Rosh Hashono at all, others wear it during the day-time services.

On Yom Kippour all Yekkes seem to wear their Kittel/Sargenes ; after their first year of marriage.

As a side point, in a typical Yekkish Kehilla, all males are expected to wear a white Käppchen - or a least a white Yarmulke - during the Rosh Hashono day services and the entire Yom Kippour services. (Most men will also wear a white tie.)

Comment: do you know where to get käppchnen on the web? I know of the custom, but there is no Jekkisch schul near me.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, in all shuls I've been to, they seem to have been handmade. Nothing obvious pops up on a Google search.

Comment: A grandson of R' Breuer's told me that when his father (the rav's son-in-law) got married, he asked R' Breuer what to do, since he was already serving as a toke'a. R' Breuer told him that he had to ask his wife permission and if she refused, that he would not be able to blow that year. I don't recall what the grandson told me the answer was.